# Outlook VBA attachments

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have some very simple .net code for creating and sending emails with/without attachments. Recently, attachments are being received as an email with the email, i.e. the recipient sees the attachment of an email message which has to be opened to see the real attachments! This never used to happen, I can only assume a product patch/windows update has caused this behaviour.

Bizarrely, when I look in the sent items of the sender PC, everything is fine - the attachments show as expected. Also, when I run the identical send code on another PC, the email is received OK with attachments showing as expected.

Basic email code:

```
Dim oOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
olNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNs.Logon()
oMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
oMail.Subject = msgSubject
oMail.HTMLBody = msgBody
oMail.To = msgTo
oMail.CC = msgCC
oMail.BCC = msgBCC

If msgAttachment <> "" Then
    If InStr(msgAttachment, ";") > 0 Then
        For x = 0 To msgAttachment.Split(";").Count - 1
            Dim g As String = ""
            g = msgAttachment.Split(";")(x)
            If g <> "" Then oMail.Attachments.Add(g)
        Next
    Else
        oMail.Attachments.Add(msgAttachment)
    End If
End If

oMail.Send()
olNs.Logoff()
oOutlook = Nothing
olNs = Nothing
oMail = Nothing
oMail = Nothing
```

The issue is in the oMail.Attachments.Add which has worked perfectly well for years.

This happens 99% of the time on this one machine and it is driving me nuts - has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  you show no code, which makes helping really hard

Comment: basic code now added